# Mongodb Aggregate query to groovy script

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jsr223

I am new to groovy scripting. I want to convert mongodb aggregate query to groovy script to query mongodb. Below is the mongodb query i want to change to groovy script:

```
db.VERISK_METADATA_COLLECTION.aggregate([
{ "$match":{contentType:"FRM"}},
{ "$project":{ "appCount": {$size:"$applicability"}}},
{ "$group": { "_id":null, Total: {$sum:"$appCount" } }},
{ "$project": {Total:1,"_id":0}}
])
```

Below is one sample record I am writing this query for:

```
{
    "_id" : "04c64247-7030-4b0e-a2f9-da77d27b8667",
    "_class" : "com.mongodb.BasicDBObject",
    "documentType" : "doc",
    "stateType" : "AZ",
    "availabilityDate" : "",
    "multiState" : "false",
    "language" : "E",
    "title" : "ARIZONA LIMITED EXCLUSION OF ACTS OF TERRORISM (OTHER THAN CERTIFIED ACTS OF TERRORISM); CAP ON LOSSES FROM CERTIFIED ACTS OF TERRORISM; COVERAGE FOR CERTAIN FIRE LOSSES",
    "displayFormNumber" : "FP 10 53 09 05",
    "mandatory" : "N",
    "client_id" : "VERISK_001",
    "ignored_record_type" : "new_publish_insert",
    "formLobType" : "FR",
    "formNumber" : "FP10530905",
    "job_queue_id" : "f8ac839f-24ee-4063-bc3c-7ed00eb91f11",
    "contentType" : "FRM",
    "directoryName" : "FRFORMS",
    "formsType" : "E",
    "objectTypeCode" : "13",
    "documentName" : "FP10539O",
    "doc_id" : [ 
        "f3f528e2-32ca-49f8-b287-b436befae779"
    ],
    "update_date" : "2017-12-27 21:05:21.189 EST",
    "earliestEffectiveDate_dt" : "2005-09-01T00:00:00Z",
    "formStatus" : "H",
    "applicability" : [ 
        {
            "filingId_dbValue_str" : "CL-2005-OFOTR",
            "jurisdiction" : "AZ",
            "withDrawnDate" : "2008-10-01T00:00:00Z",
            "filingId" : "CL-2005-OFOTR",
            "derivedFrom" : "",
            "id" : "0ef65042-6b35-460e-b12a-46766c64ff27",
            "circularNumber" : "LI-FR-2005-121",
            "lob" : "FR",
            "effectiveDate" : "2005-09-01T00:00:00Z",
            "circularDate" : "2005-07-15T00:00:00Z"
        }
    ],
    "created_date" : "2017-12-27 21:05:21.106 EST",
    "uri" : "VERISK_001/FRM/FP10530905"
}
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: to write below aggregate query in equivalent groovy script: db.VERISK_METADATA_COLLECTION.aggregate([
{ "$match":{contentType:"FRM"}},
{ "$project":{ "appCount": {$size:"$applicability"}}},
{ "$group": { "_id":null, Total: {$sum:"$appCount" } }},
{ "$project": {Total:1,"_id":0}}
])